# Can we get longitude latitude only using address through pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataset:

```
No   Address           
1    Jalan Jendral Sodirman 80 Cilacap
```

And this is my expected output

```
No   Address                                  Long             Lat
1    Jalan Jendral Sodirman 80 Cilacap        106.75           -6.45
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [Geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) libraries to find geographical coordinates, like this:

```py
import geocoder
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Address": [
            "Jalan Jendral Sodirman 80 Cilacap",
            "Jalan Jendral Sudirman 80 Cilacap",
        ]
    }
)

with requests.Session() as session:
    for address in df["Address"]:
        coo = geocoder.osm(address, session=session)
        if coo:
            df.loc[df["Address"] == address, "Long"] = round(coo.osm["x"], 2)
            df.loc[df["Address"] == address, "Lat"] = round(coo.osm["y"], 2)

print(df)
# Ouput
                             Address   Long   Lat
0  Jalan Jendral Sodirman 80 Cilacap    NaN   NaN
1  Jalan Jendral Sudirman 80 Cilacap  108.8 -7.49
```